# Activereports shrink to fit issue- textboxes

Tags: c#, activereports

In Activereports ver 7.0,

I have placed 2 textboxes one after another in vertical manner. I assigned particular width and height for both and then programmatically assigning text contents to both textboxes.

CanShrink property is set to true for both textboxes,so the textboxes can shrink to fit based on its contents.

My problem is once the first textbox shrink, I want to move the second one closely to the first one [To remove the extra space generated by shrinking], but it doesn't happen. Why is that?

Please check the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the controls only move down, not up during report run.  This is by design.  In order to accomplish what you are doing, make the textbox1 size very small to begin with, so in essence it will always grow.  In case if shrinks with not enough text you can use api to move the textbox2 up (use the location of that control in section format/before print event.